# implode not adding comma in string from loop

Tags: php, implode

I am trying to join values coming from loop with single quotes and comma.

But I don't know why comma is not getting added ?

code is :

```
<?php
 $member_course_id = array(); 
 $coursequery "select * from table.......";
 $courseresult = $database->get_results($coursequery);
    foreach ($courseresult as $coursedata){
       $member_course_id[] = $coursedata['course_id'];
  }

 $member_course_id_final =  "'".implode("','",$member_course_id)."'"; 

 echo  $member_course_id_final;
?>
```

echo is giving me output as

```
"'DBDGDFDVDFERDGDG''HJFGFHJGJFGFHGFFJ'"
```

I want it as follows :

```
"'DBDGDFDVDFERDGDG','HJFGFHJGJFGFHGFFJ'"
```

Comment: That's odd, what is `var_dump($member_course_id);` after loop?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "DBDGDFDVDFERDGDG"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "HJFGFHJGJFGFHGFFJ"
}

Comment: That output suggest 2 arrays and not 1 array with 2 items.

Comment: You need some inspection at `$coursedata['course_id']`

Comment: How does the array member_course_id look like?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try put to implode example array, just to check where might be the problem ?

```
 $member_course_id_final =  "'".implode("','",['foo','bar'])."'"; 
 var_dump ($member_course_id_final);
```

it seem thats that values are unproperly "attached" to your `$member_cours_id` array.